# ActionBar always expanded SearchView with the icon inside

Tags: android, android-actionbar, searchview

I have an ActionBar with a SearchView.

I want the search view to always be "open" (expanded). Doing that is possible using

```
mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
```

But it for some reason moves the search icon outside of the text area:
[image]

If I **don't use** setIconifiedByDefault(), it looks like I want it to look when it is expanded:
[image]

But then it collapses into a search icon on back, and also

```
MenuItemCompat.expandActionView(searchItem);
```

Does not seem to help.

Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1):

You can just intercept OnClose event:

```
searchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onClose() {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by changing my XML from

```
<item android:id="@+id/search"
android:icon="@drawable/my_icon"
app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
```

to

```
<item android:id="@+id/search"
android:icon="@drawable/my_icon"
app:showAsAction="always"
app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Always show/expand search box on an action bar

Its a 2 steps solution,

1.public void onCreateOptionsMenu(M...
      ...
      searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
}

2.
In the menu xml file, make sure android:showAsAction="always" is set

```
<item    
        android:id="@+id/grid_default_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:title="search"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
    />
```